# Limit of $x^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

The question is:
$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+}x^{1/x}.$

I have used exponent laws to re-write this as:
$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+}{e}^{\ln x/x},$ however, this does not seem to help as both $1/x$ and $\ln x$ go to $\infty$.

Comment: $\frac  1x \to \infty$ and $\ln x \to -\infty$. The product tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy's comment is the best way to think about it, but here's another way: when $x\le1$ we have $0\le x^{1/x}\le x^1$....

Comment: Both of your comments made this very clear now.  I can see that the answer is $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=\frac{1}{x}$. When $x\to 0^+$, $t$ is going to $+\infty$. So, the limit is going to become:
$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^t=\lim_{t\to +\infty}e^{-\ln(t)\cdot t}=0$$
Here, we have use the fact that:
$$a^b=e^{\ln(a)\cdot b}$$

Comment: I guess the asker just really likes exponential laws.

Comment: @Adam Neeley: I like your solution too... If you are interest in mine smash the +1 button as I've done.

Comment: Well, it's more complicated than necessary, but sure I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Substitutions are your friend.

Let $y=\frac 1 x \implies x=\frac 1 y$.

Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x^{1/x} = \lim\limits_{y\to \infty} (\frac 1 y)^{y} = \lim\limits_{y\to \infty} \frac 1 {y^y} = 0$.